# Iterate randomly over multiple lists sequentielly

Tags: python, list, random, iteration

Suppose I have three classes of objects and three lists containing multiple instances of the corresponding class. I want each object to perform a similar action n times. I can do this in a fixed order with itertools.chain (iterate over every object in first list n times, do it for the second list, etc.).

My problem is, I have to do it by random. This means: pick one object by random from one of the three lists picked by random, perform the individual action and do this till all actions are done.

So far the possible solutions I visualize are very cumbersome, maybe you can show me the pythonic way to do this...

Thanks!

Here's a simplified version of the itertools.chain solution:

```
import itertools as iter
n_objects = 10
n_actions_A = 10
n_actions_B = 2
n_actions_C = 30

Class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def action(self):
        for i in range(n_actions_A):
            self.counter += 1

Class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def action(self):
        for i in range(n_actions_B):
            self.counter += 1

Class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = 0
    def action(self):
        for i in range(n_actions_C):
            self.counter += 1

A_list = [A() for n in range(n_objects)]
B_list = [B() for n in range(n_objects)]
C_list = [C() for n in range(n_objects)]

for myobject in iter.chain(A_list, B_list, C_list):
    myobject.action()

print [myobject.counter for myobject in A_list]
```

Edit: the number of actions is different from class to class. I guess I have to build a list of sublists each one representing a single action and with a reference to the corresponding object. After the action the sublist will be deleted. The sublist will be selected via random.choice So each action has the same probability...

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: Either, have a dict how often each object has been picked and remove them from the list if they have been randomly picked 5 times, or repeat the list 5 times and just shuffle it (like a Blackjack game with 5 decks)

Comment: Also, what should be the probabilities for the three categories? If there are 8 objects left in list A and just 1 in B and C, should A be picked with probability 1/3 or 8/10?

Comment: @tobias_k Alternatively, if a list is supposed to be immutable create a list of indices and shuffle it, then iterate through `list[shuffled_indices[i]]`.

Comment: Also, should all the elements in list A have to be picked once before the first can be picked for the second time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like `random.sample` or `random.shuffle`.

Here a way to

> pick one object by random from one of the three lists picked by random, perform the individual action and do this till all actions are done

```
from random import shuffle

a = ['X','Y','Z','W']
b = ['A','B','C','D']
c = [1,2,3,4,5]

a_list = [a,b,c]
shuffle(a_list)

for _, rnd_list in enumerate(a_list):
    print(f'processing list: {rnd_list}')
    shuffle(rnd_list)
    for rnd_item in rnd_list:
        print(rnd_item)
```

The output:

```
processing list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3
5
4
1
2
processing list: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
A
C
D
B
processing list: ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'W']
W
Y
Z
X
```